# How to create ajax delete link in CViewList widget in _view file

Tags: yii

CGridView widget is already having view,update,dete option.But i am using CListView widget in my jquery mobile based project, but having problem in creating ajax link for delete option. Not getting idea how to create a ajax delete link in _view.php(view file) and its renderPartial() view file to disappear the bar after successfully deleted plz help thanks in advance. Here is the _view.php file link for edit and delete.

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), 
    array('editmember1', 'id' => $data->id), 
    array('data-role' => 'button', 'data-icon' => 'star')
);

echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), $this->createUrl('customer/delete', array('id' => $data->id)), 
    array(
       // for htmlOptions
       'onclick' => ' {' . CHtml::ajax(array(
       'beforeSend' => 'js:function(){if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))return true;else return false;}',
       'success' => "js:function(html){ alert('removed'); }")) .
       'return false;}', // returning false prevents the default navigation to another url on a new page 
       'class' => 'delete-icon',
       'id' => 'x' . $data->id)
   );
```

?>

Comment: link is almost fine, what else do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @bool.dev its not deleting the record and no error is being displayed :(

Comment: ok, currently typing an answer

Comment: @bool.dev Yes got the issue, it is due to controller delete function has set to if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) it should be changed to if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) for enabling ajax request, thanks for your quick response :)

Comment: no don't do that!! wrong practice to delete by anything other than post, see my answer it should work out. edit: also the correct url has to be called, right now your ajax will not call customer/delete, you have to set the url property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because:

1. The correct action is not being called, because you have not set the `url` property of [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You should know that Yii's `CHtml::ajax` is built on top of jQuery's ajax. So you can add :

   ```
   CHtml::ajax(array(
     ...
     'url'=>$this->createUrl('customer/delete', array('id' => $data->id,'ajax'=>'delete')),
     ...
   ))
   ```

   Also in the url i'm passing an ajax parameter so that the action knows that it's an ajax request explicitly.
2. Then the controller action by default(i.e Gii generated CRUD) expects the request to be of post type, you can see this in the customer/delete action line:`if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest){...}`. So you have to send a POST request, again modify the ajax options:

   ```
   CHtml::ajax(array(
     ...
     'type'=>'POST',
     'url'=>'',// copy from point 1 above
     ...
   ))
   ```
3. Alternatively you can also use [`CHtml::ajaxLink()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail).
4. To update the CListView after deletion, call `$.fn.yiiListView.update("id_of_the_listview");`. Something like:

   ```
   CHtml::ajax(array(
     ...
     'type'=>'POST',
     'url'=>'',// copy from point 1 above
     'complete'=>'js:function(jqXHR, textStatus){$.fn.yiiListView.update("mylistview");}'
     ...
   ))
   ```

Comment: i have updated the answer to include how to update(remove the deleted clistview bar)